# Reusing IP address from Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud

I use dedidacted IP address in SF Marketing Cloud. I would like to reuse this warmed dedicated IP address on another email service. Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The email addresses are part of the Salesforce Infrastructure, and cannot be migrated to a different email service. Neither you can migrate an IP address used elsewhere and use it as a sender IP address in SFMC.

Also, even within Salesforce, IP addresses are not very "mobile", as they can only be migrated to accounts on same stack. Hence if you are moving your account from S10 to S50, you are not able to bring your IP along, even when remaining on SFMC.

Answer (score -1):

There's no easy way out. You need a new IP and IP warming completed for the new email service.